# Does AWS SDK or CLI provide offset support on pagination when listing S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli, aws-sdk-js

Does AWS offer any kind of offset when paginating objects inside S3 bucket, either using SDK or CLI? As I am implementing regular navigation in my client, I need to have support for offset pagination when user clicks on the wanted page number.

The `StartAfter` can be used only to retrieve **next** *x* results from the defined `Key`. Also retrieving all objects from the bucket and then doing the pagination on the server breaks the pagination principle itself (it doesn't make sense).

The language I'm using is Javascript through the JS SDK, but it doesn't matter if a CLI command can be used for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ListObjects()` API call will return a maximum of 1000 objects.

If more objects are available, `isTruncated` will be True in the response and `NextContinuationToken` will contain a token that can be passed via `ContinuationToken` in a subsequent call. This will return the *next set* of results.

However, it is **not possible to directly jump to a specific page of results** (eg going from the first response of 1000 objects to the *Nth* set of results). Your code will need to sequentially request the next set until the *Nth* set of results is received.

Thus, rather than thinking of the API call as providing 'pagination', think of it as providing 'continuation' for a result set of unknown length.

If you are using the **AWS CLI**, it automatically implements the 'continuation' for you when using the `aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name` command.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So the best thing I can work with is the CLI command you provided, since it offers automatical continuation, but if my end goal is to provide regular pagination to the users with every page having max e.g. 20 objects, I need to implement offseting myself, while fetching the whole result set (which is 1000 objects max) on every page?

Comment: Yes. You wouldn't need to fetch the "whole result set", but you'd need to fetch enough to satisfy the pagination request. An alternative approach would be to maintain an up-to-date object listing in a database and then retrieve the listing from there. You can use AWS Lambda functions to update the database whenever objects are added/deleted. It takes more work (and a database!) but the results would be much quicker.